# Garbled text connecting with pyodbc to Japanese SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pyodbc

**Issue**

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL Server 2008 R2 DB via pyodbc, but all errors (regardless of the error) seem to be returned as garbled text.

- The DB user language is set to Japanese
- When the DB user language is set to English, output is not garbled.

**Example**

```
from django.db import connections
import pyodbc
con = connections['default']
con.cursor().execute('select getdate() as [abc] ', []).description

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/mypage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.5.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/mypage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Django-1.11-py3.5.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/home/ubuntu/mypage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django_pyodbc_azure-1.11.0.0-py3.5.egg/sql_server/pyodbc/base.py", line 309, in get_new_connection
    timeout=timeout)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sn����g�BU�_������ "some_database" ��Q~[�\x02����k1WW~W_\x02 (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

**Question**

Is there anything specific settings I might need to handle a database where the language is Japanese?

**Notes**

I get the feeling it's returning some sort of binary format, or that pyodbc is expecting Latin-1 or UTF16LE but getting Shift-JIS or whatever codec MS SQL Server uses for a DB set to Japanese.

The exact same garbled text happens whether I use django or just pyodbc's latest version. Have tried with both verison 11 and version 13 of the SQL Server driver.

I've spent hours searching the documentation but to no avail.
Any help would be *extremely* appreciated!

Comment: Which Django pyodbc engine are you using? `django-pyodbc-azure`? There are several forks, so please provide a link to the one you are using. There are also issues with the ODBC Driver v11 provided by Microsoft, specifically with threading and `SQLRowCount()`. You'll either want to upgrade to v13.1 or use FreeTDS. Can you also include your Django `DATABASES` setting with IPs/usernames/passwords redacted?

Comment: Also, please clarify how you are setting the "DB user language". Are you using the `Language=` parameter in the ODBC connection string, or are you referring to something else?

Comment: @FlipperPA using django-pyodbc-azure from pip (python 3)
https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure

Comment: Okay, but you haven't said precisely what you mean by "DB user language is set to Japanese". Also, based on my testing with `Language=Japanese` in the connection string I opened a [pyodbc issue](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/251) so please feel free to comment there with additional information you might deem relevant to the pyodbc side of things.

Comment: more examples (class changes based on timing of error, but the issue not the error; it's the fact it comes back garbled) 
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sn����g�BU�_������ "redacted" ��Q~[�\x02����k1WW~W_\x02 (4060) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Comment: `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]�ָ���\r 'mob_tbl' L!�gY\x02 (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Comment: @FlipperPA  
Here's DATABASES with the confidential parts redacted.  
`DATABASES = { 
'default': { 'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc', 'NAME': '-', 'USER': '-', 'PASSWORD': '-', 'HOST': '-', 'PORT': '1433', 'OPTIONS': { 'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', }, }, } `

Comment: @FlipperPA version 13.1 of the driver fails too # Error `pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]�ָ���\r 'mob_tbl' L!�gY\x02 (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")`

Comment: @GordThompson Thanks very much. Will take a look at that.